# Target another component on hover in Emotion/styled MaterialUi

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I have a Drawer Component from MUI and i style it using `styled` imported from `import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";`

How do i target `ListButton` from `ListItem`?

```
const ListButton = styled(ListItemButton)<StyledListItemButtonProps>(
  ({ theme }) => ({
    padding: 14,
    borderRadius: 8,
    minHeight: 48,
    justifyContent: "center",
  })
);

const TheListItem = styled(ListItem)(({ theme }) => ({
  display: "flex",
  ":hover": {
    ListButton: {
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.05)",
      ".MuiListItemIcon-root": {
        svg: {
          fill: theme.palette.primary.main,
        },
      },
    },
  },
}));
```

This is not working.

P.s i dont want to import it from `'@emotion/styled'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use components as selectors you should install [@emotion/babel/plugin](https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/babel-plugin).

If you want to import styled from "@mui/material/styles", you'll probably have to add an import map to provide different imports for the styled utility.

There is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-browser-4q17t5?file=/.babelrc) in [this github issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/27380#issuecomment-928973157)

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. Even though i went with classnames in my project, i see that this is working.